# Dynamically add views at xy positions in Android | Desk Booking

Tags: android, dynamic, opengl-es, android-view, android-canvas

I want to create something like in the attached image.

[image: Desk booking & placements]

Following are the operations that I want to perform:

1. Show desks(seats) at particular positions in the app(resembling my office floor map).
2. Show desk availability(blocked/available).
3. Select a desk & block it for some time.

My Plan:

- Thought of dynamically adding images(seat/desk image) at XY positions in the screen so that I can resemble my office floor map.
- While adding the images I'll also create the click listeners so that I can perform actions when the user clicks on a particular image. And I'll use different images to indicate the desk is blocked or available.

Problem:

- Tried adding `view/image` dynamically at XY position in `FrameLayout` but able to add only one view, getting an error if I try to add second `view`.
- Looked at this example [seat layout](https://github.com/varunjohn/Booking-Seats-Layout-Sample), but with this can only add the views in linear order, can't place views at desired XY location.

Is my approach correct? Any pointers/suggestions/info on achieving this will be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Can you post what kind of error do you get.

Comment: @UrbanR this is the error I got when I try to add a second view `the specified child already has a parent. you must call removeview() on the child's parent first`

Comment: And how do you add the view dynamically?